# Initialize static member with custom class in php

Tags: php, initialization, static-members

as there are no enums in PHP I tried to do something like this:

```
class CacheMode{    

    public static $NO_CACHE = new CacheMode(1, "No cache");

    private $id, $title;

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(){
        return $this->title;
    }

    private function __construct($id, $title){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I get a parse error if I run the script:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NEW
```

I "worked it aroud" with this:

```
class CacheMode{     
    public static function NO_CACHE(){
        return new CacheMode(1, __("No cache",'footballStandings'));
    }

    public static function FILE_CACHE(){
        return new CacheMode(2, __("Filecache",'footballStandings'));
    }

    public static function VALUES(){
        return array(self::NO_CACHE(), self::FILE_CACHE());
    }

    private $id, $title;

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(){
        return $this->title;
    }

    private function __construct($id, $title){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}
```

It works, but I am not really happy with it.
Can anyone explain, why I can't do the static $xyz = new XYZ(); way or has a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the manual page of [**`static`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) :

> Like any other PHP static variable,
> static properties may only be
> initialized using a literal or
> constant; expressions are not allowed.
> So while you may initialize a static
> property to an integer or array (for
> instance), you may not initialize it
> to another variable, to a function
> return value, or to an object.

That is why you cannot do

```
public static $NO_CACHE = new CacheMode(1, "No cache");
```

Comment: Hi Pascal, thx for the quick reply. The I will keep my workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Its annoying, I know. I solve it like

```
class Foo {
  public static $var;
}
Foo::$var = new BarClass;
```

Its a little bit similar to javas "static code blocks" (or whatever they are called ^^)

The file is only includeable once anyway (because a "class already define" error occurs), so you can be sure, that also the code below the class is executed once.

Comment: Hi, that's a nice approach. But then I need a public c'tor... I'll think about it... ;)

Comment: No, you dont need a public constructor. The assignment is outside of the class. That doesnt work for `protected` or `private` static properties, where you need a constructor of course.

Comment: You would if you were assigning the variable to a new instance of the class in which the variable was stored: `Foo::$var = new Foo;`

Comment: @KingCrunch. Yucks, isn't there a better solution?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, a public constructor :) `self::$var or self::$var = new Foo;`. But this requires, that you instanciate the class at least once. Beside this code outside of classes isn't wrong, or even bad. It is (dependending on the convention) "ugly" at most. Anyway, always think about, if you _really_ need statics. It is often better to configure the class instead (`setFoo()`) and pass the values from outside instead.

Comment: @KingCrunch, how can a *static* class have a constructor since we ain't going to have any instances on it at all?

Comment: @Pacerier There are no static classes in PHP and I mentioned "But this requires, that you instanciate the class at least once.". If you are not going to instanciate this class, well, there is no other way than setting it from outside, or calling a separarte (static) "setup"-method (see Michael below), or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

As an optimization, you could store the object instance as a static field, so that you are not creating a new object every time the static method is called:

```
private static $noCache;
public static function NO_CACHE(){
  if (self::$noCache == null){
    self::$noCache = new CacheMode(1, __("No cache",'footballStandings'));
  }
  return self::$noCache;
}
```

But yes, it is annoying that you cannot assign a new object instance to a class field when you first define the field. :(